# Setting new sub projects in a gradle spring boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

With grade init I set up a multi project application.

Is there a gradle command to add new sub projects? If not, what is the best way to add new projects?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a Gradle task that will add a subproject. But, this is quite easy to do yourself. Just add a subdirectory in your root project directory, and add `include("<new-subdir-name>")` to `settings.gradle` or `settings.gradle.kts`.